# Big-O Notation of an expression

Tags: asymptotics

I have the expression
$$ \frac{1}{A}\left(\ln x + \sqrt{2(\ln x-1)}\right),$$
where $A$ is a positive constant with respect to $x$.

I want to isolate the dominant term and add the error term in O-notation for $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Can someone give me a hint on how to approach this?

Comment: Hints: $\sqrt{2(\ln x -1)}=\sqrt 2\cdot\sqrt{\ln x-1}$, $\sqrt{\ln x}-\sqrt{\ln x-1}\le 1$...

Comment: @abiessu: So would you write $\frac{\ln x}{A} + O(\sqrt{\ln x})$?

Comment: That is what I would write, yes.